# Custom views style in Xamarin Cross-platform that work in all Pages for buttons and labels and textboxes

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

i try to build a class that have all the controls(views) included in my pages this class shall have  the buttons,labels,entries with customized style,i could do that by inheriting the parent element, should i make a class for every control or can i include all controls i need and inherit from the grand (View) and cast every child to its own?here is my code for only button control

```
class Styler : Button
{
    public Styler()
    {
        Text = "Login ";
        BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14, FontAttributes.Bold);
        BorderWidth = 1;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        WidthRequest = 75;
    }


}
```

but i want to not just implement button ..i want entry,labels..etc, i have to inherit from View ? P.S i am new to many c# concepts and Xamarin as well

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question exactly?

Comment: using Xamarin.Forms; my question is i want to build a class that have all controls(with custom style) i want to use them in all  pages ,i want button,label,entry..etc included in this class with custom style and use them all over the project

Answer (score 0):

What you made is mostly used for renderer to make platform specific changes, but I don't think that is what you looking for.

I think u looking for a global resource dictionary. You can create one in your app.xaml to make this global.

For a button example in the resourcedictionary:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFBC2D"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
```

This would result in everybutton to have background color "#FFBC2D" and a textcolor white.

I hope this helps

Comment: yeah thats it thanks,  : but i want it dynamically in c# i created a  shared class  and constructed every element  inside it